# Netlify SSR pages not loading

Tags: next.js, shopify, server-side-rendering, netlify

I am developing an e-commerce solution using NextJS and Shopify, and would like to host the site on Netlify.

You can find the site home page [here](https://development--nextjs-shopify-starter-tenet.netlify.app/).

Now, the issue is that Netlify returns a 502 error and times out. And the thing that really throws me for a loop is that if you click around in the site, then it works fine.

So, the link I provided above goes to the home page, which uses some server side rendering and will time out. However, if you go to the about page [here](https://development--nextjs-shopify-starter-tenet.netlify.app/about). Then click on the home page (by clicking the top left "company logo"), then everything loads fine. That makes absolutely no sense...

What could I possibly be missing? I have the netlify nextjs plugin. Everything works fine locally. And as I said, it works fine once you're clicking around within the site.

Side note: I can't release the code for confidentiality. So let's assume the api calls and stuff are all fine (I was not having this issue two weeks ago and there are branch deploys where zero code changed in that period of time). Really, I want to know if anyone has run into something like this with SSR and Netlify.

Comment: How does this relate to Shopify? What is timing out? Can you at least show snippets? Do all of your API calls have an associated catch?

Comment: It relates to shopify because, as stated, it is a shopify site. So all of the calls are shopify graphql calls. As stated, if you go to the given link, a shopify graphql call is attempted and times out. No I cannot show snippets, as stated above. And yes, they do all have try/catch blocks and all of them are set to log errors but none are thrown. This makes sense considering, as stated above, that when you go to a page that doesn't try to load data, you can click around the site without a problem.

Comment: Any page loading more 10 secs will trigger an error. I think you have deadlock or eternal loop inside your code.

Comment: right, but clearly the requests don't take 10 seconds because if you go to a page a that doesnt have SSR and then click to the home page, it loads in less than a second. Everything also works fine when working locally. Currently I'm moving all of  my service classes to Netlify functions to see if that works

Comment: actually you didn't state anything about GraphQL. Can you at least share does your home page have getServerSideProps or getInitialProps? There can be fun differences between these.

Comment: All the calls in shopify use graphql. The pages that load data all use getInitialProps to do so.

Comment: I tried to use Netlify Functions (which was an annoying amount of refactoring) and that functioned when on the live site but didn't when running locally. It was all too much of a pain to work with so I just migrated everything to Amplify and it works great.